# Extending Tensorflow Docker image file

Tags: docker, tensorflow, dockerfile

This works fine

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.9.2-gpu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git
```

This throws an error

```
FROM tensorflow/tensorflow:2.14.0-gpu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y \
    git
```

```
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke-Success '/usr/bin/test -e /usr/share/dbus-1/system-services/org.freedesktop.PackageKit.service && /usr/bin/test -S /var/run/dbus/system_bus_socket && /usr/bin/gdbus call --system --dest org.freedesktop.PackageKit --object-path /org/freedesktop/PackageKit --timeout 4 --method org.freedesktop.PackageKit.StateHasChanged cache-update > /dev/null; /bin/echo > /dev/null'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
E: Problem executing scripts APT::Update::Post-Invoke 'rm -f /var/cache/apt/archives/*.deb /var/cache/apt/archives/partial/*.deb /var/cache/apt/*.bin || true'
E: Sub-process returned an error code
```

What has changed in newer versions that breaks my Docker files?